# HTML img attribute "complete"

Tags: html, image, attributes

Can anyone explain the meaning of the attribute `complete`?

I read somewhere that it might have to do with DOM.

```
<img src="/folder/pic.jpeg" complete="complete" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's set when the image has been downloaded.

I've never seen it explicitly in the HTML like in your example ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Img) says it's not an attribute for a `img` element) . I just use to check if the image has been downloaded with JavaScript (there are cross browser issues with that, however). The property on a `HTMLImageElement` returns a `Boolean`.

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelector("img"), function(img) {
    // Loaded?
    img.complete && (img.style.border = "5px solid #f00");
});
```

Comment: Is it worth pointing out that it's a non-standard tag, and that it's added by some javascript (likely in an onload handler of the image) rather than the browser itself?

Comment: @Zaffy Sure, but it has its own problems.

Comment: If you inspect an img tag with the IE developer tools, you'll see `complete="complete"`, which surprised me and led me to this question.

Answer (score 11):

The attribute `complete` has no defined meaning by specifications, and it probably has no effect (though it can be read with the `getAttribute()` method). So the code in the question is probably based on some misunderstanding.

According to HTML5 drafts, there is the `complete` *property* for an object corresponding an `img` element, as per the `HTMLImageElement` interface. The [definition of the `complete` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-img-complete) basically means that the value is true when the browser has completely received the image (though there are some nuances here). As this is to be controlled by the browser, reflecting the loading status, it is natural that the property is defined to be read-only.

This property is widely present browsers, but apparently in a broken way: if you have an `img` element that refers to a nonexistent resource (404 Not Found), then Chrome and Firefox indicate the property as having the value true (IE gets things right here: false). So the property is not of much use for the time being.

Setting an attribute in HTML has no effect on this. HTML attribute and element object properties correspond to each other only when a correspondence has been defined.

Comment: Turns out, IE got it wrong, at least [according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-img-complete).  I'd say that everyone got it wrong - a simple boolean is not enough.  We need something more robust like a status, eg loaded, loading, not found, invalid format, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to check if the image has finished loading.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].complete
```

returns true if has finished loading, else false.
However it is not used as an attribute like in your example.