# onload vs onLoad (case sensitivity)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have 2 functions(`js`) in a webpage for attaching an image to a canvas element:

```
 function attachImage(tile, x, y)
    {
      base_image = new Image();
      base_image.src = 'Images/tiles/'+(tile-1)+'.png';
      base_image.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(base_image, 32*x,32*y);
      }
    }
```

and i literally copy and pasted it and duplicated it for another canvas

```
  function attachImage2(tile2, x2, y2)
    {
        base_image2 = new Image();
        base_image2.src = 'Images/tiles/'+(tile2-1)+'.png';
        base_image2.onLoad = function(){
            context2.drawImage(base_image2, 32*x2,32*y2);
      }
    }
```

On firefox, if i make one `onload` and the other `onLoad`, then it works fine. but no matter what i do for chrome, it doesn't load the images properly.

edit: here is and image comparison between firefox and chrome:

FIREFOX: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5sMt.jpg

CHROME: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u12H6.jpg

Comment: do not use the **>** block quotes for code. either use `<code></code>`, or select your code and press the **{}** symbol from the toolbar.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli thank you very much! Will do so next time and onwards :)

Comment: The `onLoad` property does not work for me in Firefox, and I don't know why it would. If you're talking about attributes, that's a different story.

Comment: In JavaScript the names need to be all lower-case.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli no, `<code>` is kind-of undesirable. Markdown code syntax is a four-space indent.

Comment: sorry guys :( i just pressed control+K like it told me to

Comment: Maybe declare the `onload` property before the `src` property?

Comment: Also, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933230/javascript-image-onload

Comment: @pointy, you are right and i know... I just thought it might be easier for a newcomer..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli yes that's all good!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `onload` (*lowercase*).

Some general notes

- When you need local variables use `var`.
- You should set the `onload` before actually setting the `src` because otherwise (*for cached*) images the `onload` might not get called.
- Since your methods do the same thing, you should use only one, and pass the context as a parameter

So

```
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('map');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var canvas2 = document.getElementById('map2');
context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

function attachImage(tile, x, y, canvasContext)
{
  var base_image = new Image();
  base_image.onload = function(){
    canvasContext.drawImage(base_image, 32*x,32*y);
  }
  base_image.src = 'Images/tiles/'+(tile-1)+'.png';
}
</script>
```

and you should not create a `script` tag for each call

```
<?php
echo("<script>");
for($tr = 0; $tr < count($mapArray)-1; $tr++) {
    for($tc = 0; $tc < count($mapArray[$tr])-1; $tc++) {
        $tile = $mapArray[$tr][$tc];
        echo "attachImage(" . $tile . "," . $tc . "," . $tr . ",context);";
    }
}

for($tr = 0; $tr < count($mapArrayy)-1; $tr++) {
    for($tc = 0; $tc < count($mapArrayy[$tr])-1; $tc++) {
        if($mapArrayy[$tr][$tc]!=0){
            echo "attachImage(" . $mapArrayy[$tr][$tc]. "," . $tc . "," . $tr . ",context2);";
        }
    }
}
echo("</script>");
?>
```

Comment: omg thanks a lot! it's fixed! and i would have never thought of putting the script tag out of the loop!

Comment: @Wulf, also - you should be getting the canvas elements and their contexts in a function that is called as the document's onload callback. Otherwise, you may not get the canvas elements since that part of the page hasn't loaded yet. I always put window.addEventListener('load', myInitFunc, false); as the first line of the script, with the myInitFunc function starting on the second line. You know that when myInitFunc is called, that the DOM is guaranteed to have loaded. Much the same as the onload trick with the images.