# Updating an Image and resize them faults

Tags: javascript, image, image-uploading

I am uploading an image via ajax and wanna instantly update them in the user profile picture element.

it works but the problem is, that the image is not moved perfectly until i refreshed the site 1-2 times.

```
var t = new Date().getTime(),
    avatar = $("img.user-avatar"),
    src = avatar.attr("src");
src = src.substr(0, src.indexOf("?") > 0 ? src.indexOf("?") : src.length);
avatar.attr("src", src + "?" + t);
resizeAndMoveAvatar();
```

the resizeAndMoveAvatar() function looks like this:

```
function resizeAndMoveAvatar()
{
    var Avatar = $("img.user-avatar");
    var w = Avatar.width(), h = Avatar.height();
    Avatar.css({
        'max-width': 'none',
        'max-height': 'none'
    });

    if(w > h) {
        Avatar.css('max-height', 32);
        w = Avatar.width();
        Avatar.css('left', -(w/2 - 32/2));
    }
    else if(h > w) {
        Avatar.css('max-width', 32);
        h = Avatar.height();
        Avatar.css('top', -(h/2 - 32/2));
    }
    else {
        Avatar.css({width: 32, height: 32});
    }
}
```

when I update it its look like this:
[image: WRONG]

but it should like this:
[image: RIGHT]

any suggestions how I can fix this problem?

thank you!

Comment: Try using an image.onLoad event to fire your method. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933230/javascript-image-onload)

Comment: I know what you mean, I think this will work for me

Comment: Uhm yea.. used the loadevent, definetly called but the resizing fail again. I would say it is a cache problem with FF. Same fail in Chrome and in IE and Safari it does not works completly but that is just a compatibility problem.

Comment: Yeah it could be alright. Maybe have a look into disabling the cache on that picture?

Comment: fixed the issue. I'm using now an image, that is already resized and moved into center. it works pretty well with updating it. thank you anyway :)

Comment: Nice one, could you post the code / show what you've done in the answer section for future viewers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Celt requested for my solution:
I update the image as before, the only change is that I don't using the resizeAndMoveAvatar function anymore because the image that I need is already resized and moved into center by a PHP-Script

works very well for me

my class: http://pastebin.com/DffcfnyC
used in like this:

```
$Img = new Image("path/to/image.png"); // creating an instance
$Img->Square(); // center the image
$Img->Resize(32, 32); // resize it
$Img->Save("path/to/destination/image.png"); // and finally save it
```

love it